# Handle Mutil Part Param in PHP post

Tags: php, android

In android client , I already set multi- params for http post request .( I make 
sure have connection between android client and my webservice .)

Android Code :

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"
 Content-Type: text/plain
 123`

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"
 Content-Type: text/plain
 tuyenpx`

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="studio.png"
 Content-Type: image/png
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`

["Data here , already write to output stream of connect"]

PHP code :

```
 if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
        $userName = $_GET['username'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['password'])) {
        $passWord = $_GET['password'];
    }

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['filename'], "uploads/" . $_FILES['file']['filename']);


  //  if (!($userName == '' && $passWord == '')) {
        $json = array("status" => TRUE, "username" => $userName,"password"=>$passWord);
        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK', true, 200);
        response($json);
//    } else {
//        header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
//        header('Content-type: text/plain; charset = UTF8');
//        echo'invalid request , username or pass wo`enter code here`rd must not null';
```

**Question** : what I am wrong in PHP code , why `$_GET['username']` always return null , and I also try with `$_POST['username']` , it also return null  .

Thank you for your help !

Comment: *******************
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"
Content-Type: text/plain
123
*******************
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"
Content-Type: text/plain
tuyenpx
*******************
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="studio.png"
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

["Data here , already write to output stream of connect"] 
*******************

Comment: `Android Code :`. That is no code. That is data. And i see no boundaries. You better post the code as already has been asked.

Comment: Hi , I am sure my HTTP client worked fine , because I already capture http post package and checked , in my task , I only post 2 tring params and one file (PNG ) as multipart , key of 2 string params is 'username' and 'password' . and key of file PNG is 'file" . so can you help me in PHP server side , because my client is one my library , so difficult to copy here . Thank you in advance .

Comment: addition information , I already use wireshark and take the pcap log which send from my emulator , and every think seem be fine , can you help me in PHP code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your times , and I resolved my question in my PHP server, and in my library also lackof one boundary in the end of body to finish write outputstream .

$userName = $_POST['username'];
    $passWord = $_POST['password'];

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    $uploads_dir = './';
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $pic_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir . $pic_name);
    $json = array("status" => TRUE, "msg" => "upload success","username"=>$userName,"password"=>$passWord);
    response($json);
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
}
```